# UINavigationController Presenting Modal View Controller Displays Grey Screen While Loading

Tags: ios, iphone, cordova, uinavigationcontroller, presentviewcontroller

The following code sets up my UIWindow and UINavigationController from which I want to present modal view controllers:

```
self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    ViewController *controller = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];
    self.navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:controller];
    self.window.rootViewController = self.navController;
    [self.window setHidden:FALSE];
```

Once I set this all up I display a Controller that is provided by a third party library using:

```
[self.navigationController presentViewController:self.presentedViewController
                                        animated:NO
                                      completion:nil];
```

While the Modal View Controller is loading there seems to be a grey screen that is displayed, wondering how I can hide this during the load of the modal controller.

Comment: Where are you calling presentViewController, and what is self.presentedViewController? The presented view controller should point to a controller that you (you being the controller where you have this presentation code) presented already -- it doesn't make sense to have your navigation controller try to present it again.

Comment: Sorry if that is misleading, I just changed the name for the purpose of the question, self.presentedViewController is a third party library UIViewController so I don't have access to the source of it but it essentially brings up a camera view to capture an image and then will return that image in a delegate method where I then dismiss that controller.

Comment: Well, there's nothing in the code you posted that should cause your problem, so it's going to be hard to diagnose.

Comment: A little background information that may help is that I am using a Cordova Plugin from Non-Native side that spawns this UIWindow / Navigation controller. As well the Third Party Controller does a second or two to initialize which is why I think the Grey Screen is displaying, but maybe there is some way to hide it or not even display it to begin with while the controller actually loads.